# Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog theme remove default app bar

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I am trying to add a custom tool bar to this activity which uses the theme
`Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog` but the main issue is to remove the already existing default tool bar and put the custom tool bar on top.

[image: Screenshot of what i have right now]

I have tried creating new styles parenting the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog` theme with no luck.
Also the default tool bar doesn't have the settings popup icon as in the custom tool bar. Any ideas that you might have will surely be appreciated.

**Found a Solution**

Changed the style of the dialog by

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.custom">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

This style extends the Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog theme